# Exit issues within a batch file that is being called from a for loop

Tags: batch-file

I have an issue with the exit status of a child script going back to the parent script (child being called by a for loop).

Syntax of Parent script:

```
for /f "usebackq" %%i in (`dir/b /o:d %partionHome%\tmp\queue\*.t~#`) do call "%partionHome%\conf\SQLLoader\SQL_Loader_%DSNname%
\SQLLoader_UA_SYSTEM_TABLES.bat" %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 "%%i" %has_prefix% "%partionHome%"
echo ERRORLEVEL_Master %ERRORLEVEL%                                                 >> %logfile%
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 goto :failed
goto :end
:end
echo Executed loop >> %logfile%
echo got out >> %logfile%
echo Success >> %logfile%
exit 0
:failed
echo Load Failed >> %logfile%
exit 1
```

THE CHILD SCRIPT:

```
"%sqlbinn%\sqlcmd.exe" -S %dbHost% -d %databaseName% -U %userName% -P %pwd% -Q "BULK INSERT %databaseName%.dbo.%tableName% FROM '%bulkloader%\%DATA_FILE%' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = '|', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n', 
FORMATFILE='%bulkloader%\%CTRL_FILE%')" >> %logfile% 2>&1
echo ERRORLEVEL %ERRORLEVEL%                                                >> %logfile%
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 goto :errors
goto :doneld
:doneld
echo i am here3 >> %logfile%
echo * Delete the control and data file from the shared directory           >> %logfile%
del %confdirectory%\%DATA_FILE%
del %confdirectory%\%CTRL_FILE%
set H=%time:~-10,1%
if %time:~-11,2% LSS 10 (set Hour=%time:~-10,1%) else (setHour=%time:~-11,2%)
set M=%time:~-8,2%
set s=%time:~-5,2%
echo **   SQLLoad ENDS  %H%:%M%:%s%                                         >> %logfile%
echo i am here4 >> %logfile%
EXIT /B 0
:errors
echo i am here5 >> %logfile%
echo *                                                                      >> %logfile%
echo WARNING! Error(s) were detected in the SQL loader utility!             >> %logfile%
echo Please check the data file, control file or the SQL loader utility     >> %logfile%
echo *                                                                      >> %logfile%
echo sqlloaderERROR check log file %logfile% >> %logDirectory%\sqlloaderlogs\LOAD_ERROR_DETECTED_%Day%-%Mth%-%Yr%_%Hour%_%Min%_%sec%_%msec%
time /t >> %logfile%
EXIT /B 1
```

The SQL command works and the data is uploaded, the log records that it does everything it should and outputs  "echo i am here4", but for some reason the process repeats itself for about 22 times (running sqlcmd.exe) and then exit's correctly (echo Executed loop, echo Success etc. from the master script)?????

I thought the EXIT /B * should return an error code to the master script for it to be evaluated (which I have) but it does not and just loops round and tries to run sqlcmd.exe over and over again eventually succeeding and closing?

Answer (score 0):

The `exit /b 1` stops your child script and set the errorlevel to 1.

Why it should stop anything else?
It neither stops your parent script nor the loop.
`exit /b` works a bit like `return` in other languages.

You can test in the loop the errorlevel and then stop the loop (with a `goto :label`).

Like

```
for /f %%i in (`dir/b queue\*.t`) do (
  call child
  if errorlevel 1 goto :break
)
:break
```

Comment: sorry, fairly new to this, i understand it needs to break the for loop somehow. I assume you can apply the following for /f "usebackq" %%i in (`dir/b /o:d %partionHome%\tmp\queue\*.t~#`) do call "%partionHome%\conf\SQLLoader\SQL_Loader_%DSNname%

\SQLLoader_UA_SYSTEM_TABLES.bat" %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 "%%i" %has_prefix% "%partionHome%" ( if errorlevel 1 goto :failed if errorlevel 0 goto :end
)

Comment: You need to enclose the complete code block in parenthesis, not only the `( if errorlevel ....` also the `call "%partion ....`

Comment: ok, reran like this: for /f "usebackq" %%i in (`dir/b /o:d %partionHome%\tmp\queue\*.t~#`) do ( call "%partionHome%\conf\SQLLoader\SQL_Loader_%DSNname%

\SQLLoader_UA_SYSTEM_TABLES.bat" %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 "%%i" %has_prefix% "%partionHome%" if errorlevel 1 goto :failed if errorlevel 0 goto :end
)

Comment: ok, reran like this: for /f "usebackq" %%i in (`dir/b /o:d %partionHome%\tmp\queue\*.t~#`) do ( call "%partionHome%\conf\SQLLoader\SQL_Loader_%DSNname%

\SQLLoader_UA_SYSTEM_TABLES.bat" %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 "%%i" %has_prefix% "%partionHome%" if errorlevel 1 goto :failed if errorlevel 0 goto :end
) - however the process still loops and calls the sqlcmd.exe within SQLLoader_UA_SYSTEM_TABLES.bat multiple times before the errorlevel goes to 0 to the loop and exits gracefully from the parent script. However within the logging from the child script shows it fully works on the first time around?